# iteration of array elements in mult multi dimensional way

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I have the following array setup for a category, variation and sub variation to be implemented on cascading ajax selection.

```
$config['categories']= array(

 'MEN'=>array(
        'Tanks',
        'Bags & Wallets'=>array('Backpacks','Briefcases','Messenger bags','Wallets'),
        'Belts & Buckles',
        'Bottoms'=>array('Pants','Shorts','Swim','Underwear'),
        'Coats & Jackets'=>array('Blazers','Coats','Jackets'),
        'Cufflinks',
        'Hats',
        'Shirts',
        'Shoes',
        'Suits',
        'Sweaters',
        'T-Shirts',
        'Ties', 
        'Clips & Bow Ties',
        'Other Clothing',
        'Other Accessories'

    ),
    'WOMEN'=>array(
        'Accessories'=>array('Belts','Eyewear','Gloves & Mittens','Hats           Legwear','Scarves','Watches','Shoe Accessories'),
        'Bags & Purses',

    )
);
```

I'm building a cascading category drop-down list using ajax.

```
public function get_sub_categories_ajax() {

         $categories_selected = $this->input->post('category');  
         $load_all_catagories = $this->config->item('categories');


         $result = $load_all_catagories[strtoupper($categories_selected)];
         $subcategories = array();
          foreach($result as $key => $value) {

           $subcategories[$key] = $value;

         }

         if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

            exit('Not allowed');

         } else {

            $result =  array('#'=>'Please Select Variation')+$result;

            header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8'); 
            echo ( json_encode( array_values($subcategories)  )  );
         } 
    }
```

The problem I'm having is when **"women"** is selected on I want return the following values **[accessories, bags and purse]** and when **"bags"** is selected I would like to list **empty**. Similarly, when **accessories** is selected I want to return **['Belts','Eyewear','Gloves]**.

Comment: This is such a small amount of content, why not write entire data structure to javascript and do away with asynchronous communications (i.e. not require calls to server to traverse the data structure)?

Comment: mike brant just give me example